# Converting mark space ratio to DC

Tags: analog, dac, instrumentation

I have a pulse which varies between 500 Hz to 100 kHz where the quantity I need is the mark space ratio, I'm not interested in the frequency here although it must affect the design. What I've come up with is the sketch below. I think it should work but my math is rubbish, I have no idea how to calculate the values, can anyone help?

[image: Mark space -> DC sketch]

Comment: How stable is the amplitude of the incoming square wave? What accuracy and resolution are you looking to achieve?

Comment: The incoming wave is as stable as rotating machinery can get. The output will be an indication rather than a value to 3dp, and will probably be displayed on an analog meter.

Comment: How stable is "as stable as rotating machinery can get"? This dictates as to whether you can use the method shown in the first answer or a different and a little more complex method. I'm not asking my question out of nosiness. Accuracy is still an issue that dictates the design methodology and without some idea of accuracy this question is difficult to answer accurately as well.

Comment: Didn't mean to put your nose out of joint. Stability in itself is not a particularly easy quantity to define. The machine speed is locked via PLL, the input wave is already pre-processed and the board will be tested via a function generator. I considered that the statement of using an analog meter implied that accuracy will be low, of the order of 2-3% FS. I'm a little concerned that the circuit might lose linearity at high 'mark' ratios as the capacitor becomes fully charged, although it's only intended as an 'is-it-working' unit.

Comment: If there is a change in the peak voltage from your input then that will be reflected to the output.  You could clean up the input with a comparator.

Comment: Kelvin-Herz is not a measure of anything useful to this discussion.

Comment: George - The input already comes from a comparator and assorted logic. Olin - Kelvin-Herz??

Comment: Why are you asking me?  You're the one that specified the pulse to be up to 100 Kelvin-Herz.  The point is that this makes no sense.

Comment: I'm talking about amplitude stability of the incoming waveform - if you use a low pass filter to give you a measure of mark space, this will be 50% in error if the amplitude of the sq wave halved. Nose still intact but remember it's a little "k" for kilo.

Answer (score 1):

You want a plain old low pass filter.  What you show is a peak detector, which won't give you the average level.

One way to look at this is that you have a low frequency signal you want to measure, but it has 500 Hz to 100 kHz pulses superimposed on it.  The solution is to filter out frequency components of 500 Hz and higher, leaving the desired signal.  A simple series of R-C filters will do this.  The exact design of the filter depends on what the upper frequency content of the duty cycle signal is, and the minimum signal to noise ratio you require.  You didn't specify those, so here is a quick stab at it:

[image]

The rolloff of each R-C is 100 Hz, so 500 Hz will be attenuated by about 5 each stage, and 5<sup>3</sup> = 125 for all stages.  Actually the 500 Hz attenuation will be a bit more than that, but this gives you a quick minimum figure.  Put another way, this is good to 7 bits accuracy.

As a separate issue, you should put the opamp after this filter, not before it.  The opamp response to sudden steps will be non-linear, distorting the result.  The filter also adds significant impedance, which following with a buffer fixes.

Comment: The usable range will be 10-90%, which I believe will give an upper freq of 1MHz but am happy to be corrected. The application was hoped to cover 2 machines, one with a range of 500Hz to 30kHz, the other 2kHz to 100kHz+. Would it be better to fit a range switch to tailor the response better?

Comment: @Lones: It depends on the highest frequency of interest of the duty cycle signal.  If you can separate it well enough from the lowest possible PWM frequency, then a single filter is fine.  If not, tailor the filter to the PWM frequency and duty cycle frequency.

Answer (score 0):

The envelope detector isn't really going to give a level based on the mark space ratio. It's going to give you the same pulses but with slower rise and fall times.

I would recommend removing the diode and R2, and then choosing R1 and the cap to form a low pass filter at around 150hz. you can use this formula:

[image]

Pass this result into another buffer and you have your result:

[image]

You could even hook up a window detector/comparator at the output to get a high or low voltage depending.

Comment: 150kHz  really? I guess that's a typo.

Comment: Indeed, changed to 150hz